# Hive INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera

I am using Cloudera 5.3.3 Hive.

I am trying to execute the below query,

```
shell>pwd
/home
shell> mkdir test; chmod 777 test;
shell> ls -al
drwxrwxrwx   3 jai jai  4096 Oct  5 06:45 test  

 hive query>INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/test/test1' SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

It is working fine, and creating output files inside **/home/test** folder when I am executing from hive client, but it is not creating the files if I am executing the same from **beeline**.

Connecting to **Hive server 2** via **beeline** from the machine where Hive server 2 is running.

I am connecting hive from beeline as a **jai** user.
The folder /home/test

The same query, working fine if I am pointing to **/tmp** folder (where test folder has 777 permission). It is copying the mapreduce output into test1 folder, which has following permission and created as hive user.

```
shell>pwd
/tmp
shell> ls -al
drwxrwxrwx   5 jai jai 4096 Oct  5 06:40 test      

beeline as jai user>  INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/test/test1' SELECT * FROM some_table;

shell> cd test;
shell> ls -al
drwxr-xr-x   3 hive     hive     4096 Oct  5 06:37 test1
```

Comment: Could it be security settings? You can grant/deny privileges to HiveServer2 in Sentry, for instance, which will not be respected by the legacy Hive client.

Comment: @HellmarBecker And there are no error entries in HiveServer2 logs.

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the observed behavior could be related to the issue [HIVE-11666](https://issues-test.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-11666).

> Hive CLI writes to local host when INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY. But Beeline writes to HS2 local directory. For a user migrating from CLI to Beeline, it might be a big chance (sic).

The workaround could be to export it to HDFS

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 'hdfs://<cluster>/tmp/test/test1' SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

*Note: Do not forget to use the fully qualified path (starting with `hdfs//`) since it will not work otherwise (see [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/112754/insert-overwrite-directory-beeline.html))*

Then simply get it

```
hdfs dfs -get hdfs://<cluster>/tmp/test/test1/<file name>
```